# Palavra-chave callable no PHP

Tags: php, callback, indução-de-tipo

A palavra chave `callable` foi implementado a partir do PHP 5.4.

Ela provê uma maneira de tipar um argumento de uma função, obrigando que o tipo de argumento seja um `callback`.

Exemplo:

```
function minha_funcao($a, callable $func)
{
    return $func($a * 8); 
}

minha_funcao(9, function(){ return 5 * 10; });
```

Eu costumava, em casos como esse, utilizar a classe `Closure` para fazer a indução de tipo desse segundo parâmetro.

Exemplo:

```
function minha_funcao($a, \Closure $func)
{
}
```

Sendo assim tenho alguns perguntas

- Qual é a diferença entre a indução de `callable` para `Closure`?
- Quais são as vantagens de se usar `callable`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Qual é a diferença entre a indução e tipo feita por callable e Closure?

A diferença é que, na declaração de indução de tipo, quando utilizamos `Closure`, estamos informando que aquela função ou método deve passar como parâmetro *apenas* funções anônima.

Já no caso da palavra chave `callable`, quando utilizamos ela como indução de tipo do parâmetro da função ou método, estamos informando que esta aceitará como parâmetro um callback, independente de ser uma função anônima ou não.

Nesse caso, devemos aceitar os seguintes parâmetros que serão aceitos:

- `string` que representem nome de funções ou métodos estáticos. Ex: `"print_r"`, `"max"`, `"Classe::nomeDoMetodo"`
- `array` com dois elementos, que represente `classe` e `método`. Nesse caso, o primeiro parâmetro pode ser uma instância do `objeto` (no caso de chamada normal) ou a string da classe (no caso da chamada estática).Ex: `array('Classe', 'nomeDoMetodo')` ou `array(new Classe, 'nomeDoMetodo')`.
- `classe` que implemente o método mágico `__invoke` (como é o caso da classe `Closure` pra quem não sabe, uma `Closure` pode ter o método `__invoke` acessado).

## Qual é a vantagem e usar callable?

A principal vantagem pode ser vista com dois exemplos:

Exemplo sem `callable`:

```
function minha_funcao($callback)
{
     if (is_callable($callback)) return $callback();
}
```

Exemplo:

```
function minha_funcao($callback)
{
    return $callback();
}
```

**Observação**: É possível tanto na indução de tipo de `Closure` e `callable` é possível definir um valor `NULL` por padrão.

Assim sendo, podemos fazer isso:

```
function minha_funcao($a, callable $func = NULL) {
   if (! is_null($func)) return $a * 8;

   return $func($a * 8);
}
```